# Construct circle center from chord

Tags: geometric-construction

Is it possible to construct the center of a circle from a single chord?

If I construct the perpendicular bisector of the chord and then construct the perpendicular bisector of that, wouldn't the exact point of intersection be the center of the circle?

[image: This is what I imagined.]

Comment: No....the chord may not pass through the center.  Of course your bisector passes through the center but you can't tell where.  Two chords in general position gets the job done!

Comment: If you meant: "if I construct the perp. bisector of the cord, **form a cord with this perp. bisector** ....etc.", then yes: that perp. bisector is going to be a diameter and thus bisecting it you get the circle's center. +1

Comment: @DonAntonio that was what I meant yes.

Comment: Then yes: you're correct. Well done.

Comment: I don't understand.  The perpendicular bisector is an (infinite) line.  It is not a diameter.

Comment: @lulu please see the attached picture

Comment: @DonAntonio So there is no chance, with any chord, that this procedure goes wrong?

Comment: Just to give an explicit example:  in the Cartesian Plane let $P=(-1,0)$ and $Q=(1,0)$.  Then the perpendicular bisector of $PQ$ is the $y$-axis.  Those two points lie on infinitely many circles.  They lie on $x^2+y^2=1$ for example, but also on $x^2+(y-a)^2= 1+a^2$ for all $a$.

Comment: @lulu but you have been given a circle already.

Comment: I don't understand that picture at all.  One chord does not determine a circle uniquely, as my last comment illustrates.

Comment: @lulu I'm not trying to determine a circle, I'm trying to determine a center by construction.

Comment: What do you mean you've been given a circle?  You never said that.  How are you given the circle?  If I have other points on it, then I can make several chords.  All you need is two non-parallel chords.  Then you can intersect the two perpendicular bisectors.  Three points is enough.

Comment: @lulu and A.G this is a task in geometric construction as the tag suggests. Imagine someone has drawn a circle and a chord, I would like to determine where the center of the circle is. No algebra is involved in this.

Comment: @Neutronic As far as I can see it, no. We have the basic theorem in Euclidean geometry: when we have a cord in a circle (= a line segment joining two distinct points of a circle), then the cord's perpendicular bisector passes through the circles center (the other direction is also true, so this is an iff theorem). Thus, as I noted in my first comment, if the cord's perp. bisec. is made into a cord (meaning: take the segment of the perp. bis. joining two different points on the circle), it is *always* a diameter.

Comment: As I say:  if you have three distinct points $P,Q,R$ on the circle then form the two chords $PQ$ and $PR$.  Draw the two perpendicular bisectors...they intersect at the center of the circle.

Comment: Whoa...  The OP has a circle, then draws a chord, then the perpendicular bisector of that chord to get a chord which is a diameter of the circle. Now bisecting the diameter yields the center of the circle.

Comment: @MaxW Exactly so. That's precisely how I understood it from the beginning.

Comment: @DonAntonio Thank you. Please add an answer with you comments so I can accept. 

MaxW thats how I understood Don's first answer aswell but thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have the basic theorem in Euclidean geometry: when we have a cord in a circle (= a line segment joining two distinct points of a circle), then the cord's perpendicular bisector passes through the circles center (the other direction is also true, so this is an iff theorem). Thus, as I noted in my first comment, if the cord's perp. bisec. is made into a cord (meaning: take the segment of the perp. bis. joining two different points on the circle), it is always a diameter

Answer (score 1):

Yes definitely. This is because the perpendicular bisector of the chords is the diameter of the circle, and it's bisector will definitely be the centre.